# Unexpected unequal sharing of data between nodes

Tags: cassandra

I have configured cassandra cluster with 4 nodes with 2 seeds. When I run nodetool status, the owns for the individual nodes are as follows,

```
node1 (seed1)    - 24.5%
node2            - 15.0%
node3(seed2)     - 46.1%
node4            - 14.5%
```

should owns should have equal %. If so how can i make that equal. And when i make down node2 and node4 i can able to insert/retrieve data with replication factor 2. But when i make node1 or node2 i can not.Getting the following exception,

```
SEVERE: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HUnavailableException: : May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level.
java.lang.Exception: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HUnavailableException: : May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level.
    at com.july.storage.cassandra.util.CassandraDBUtil.getData(CassandraDBUtil.java:197)
    at com.july.storage.cassandra.util.CassandraDBUtil.doSelect(CassandraDBUtil.java:370)
    at com.july.storage.cassandra.action.CassandraHandler.getCall(CassandraHandler.java:127)
    at com.july.storage.service.StorageService.GET(StorageService.java:58)
    at com.july.storage.cassandra.action.CassandraHandler.main(CassandraHandler.java:571)
Caused by: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HUnavailableException: : May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level.
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:59)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.CqlQuery$1.execute(CqlQuery.java:130)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.CqlQuery$1.execute(CqlQuery.java:100)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:103)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.CqlQuery.execute(CqlQuery.java:99)
    at com.july.storage.cassandra.util.CassandraDBUtil.getData(CassandraDBUtil.java:179)
```

Thanks,
Sangeetha

Comment: Which version of Cassandra? Also, please make an effort to format the stack traces and examples in your questions, it will make it easier for us to understand your question, and increase the likelyhood of you getting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

An imbalance can depend on a lot of factors, and you haven't given us very much to go on.

- How much data is in your cluster? If there's not very much then this is completly normal. If you only have a thousand rows in the cluster then it's extremely unlikely that you would get an even distribution.
- Have you enabled vnodes? If you're using a recent version, like 1.2.5, this is enabled by default. If you have an older version or have disabled vnodes then it's not uncommon to have unbalanced nodes. You can mode nodes manually using `nodetool`, but don't do it on your production system, test it first in a test environment.
- Which partitioner are you using? If you don't know you're using a random partitioner, which should increase the likelihood of an even distribution, but if you've changed to an ordered partitioner you can't expect to get even distribution, you need to move the nodes manually as you add data to the cluster.

The reason why you can't retrieve data when two nodes are down is probably that the row you're retrieving resided on those two nodes, with only four nodes and a replication factor of two it's quite likely -- especially since you can get the data when only the other two nodes are up. Try another row and you will most likely get different results, and try changing the consistency level of the request to one (you didn't say what consistency level you were using, so I assume you're reading at quorum, which with a replication factor of two means that both nodes must be up).

Comment: I am using cassandra 1.2.5. Yes I dont have much data. I just configured and tested. I am using murmur3partitioner.

Comment: When only try to post with two nodes up also i am getting the same exception "May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level"

Comment: Check the consistency level on the requests, if it's anything else than `one` the chance of success is slim (and even with `one` it's not guaranteed with half the cluster down). What is it that you expect? You ask the cluster to write to N nodes, and it tells you that it can't because there aren't enough nodes up to guarantee that. Lower your consistency requirements, or add more nodes.

Comment: He should also ensure that the nodes have equal numbers of tokens?